# Long-running Redshift transaction from Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-redshift, pg

I run several sql statements in a transaction using Ruby pg gem. The problem that I bumped in is that connection times out on these queries due to firewall setup. Solution proposed [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-firewall-guidance.html) does not work, because it requires jdbc connections string, and I'm in Ruby (jRuby is not an option). Moving driver program to AWS to remove firewall is not an option either.

The code that I have is along the following lines:

```
conn = RedshiftHelper.get_redshift_connection
begin
  conn.transaction do
    # run my queries
  end
ensure
  conn.flush
  conn.finish
end
```

I'm now looking into PG asynchronous API. I'm wondering if I can use is_busy to prevent firewall from timing out, or something to that effect. I can't find good documentation on the topic though. Appreciate any hints on that.

PS: I have solved this problem for a single query - I can trigger it asynchronously and track its completion using system STV_INFLIGHT Redshift table.Transaction does not work this way as I have to keep connection open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I nailed it down. Here are the facts:

1. Redshift is based on Postgres 8.0. To check that, connect to Redshift instance using psql and see that it says "server version 8.0"
2. Keepalive requests are specified on the level of tcp socket ([link](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html)).
3. Postgres 8.0 does not support keepalive option when specifying a connection string ([link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/release-9-0.html) to 9.0 release changes, section E.19.3.9.1 on libpq)
4. PG gem in Ruby is a wrapper about libpq

Based on the facts above, tcp keepalive is not supported by Redshift. However, PG allows you to retrieve a socket that is used in the established connection. This means that even though libpq does not set keepalive feature, we still can use it manually. The solution thus:

```
 class Connection

      attr_accessor :socket, :pg_connection

      def initialize(conn, socket)
        @socket = socket
        @pg_connection = conn
      end

      def method_missing(m, *args, &block)  
        @pg_connection.send(m, *args, &block)
      end        

      def close
        @socket.close
        @pg_connection.close
      end

      def finish
        @socket.close
        @pg_connection.close
      end
    end     

def get_connection
      conn = PGconn.open(...)
      socket_descriptor = conn.socket
      socket = Socket.for_fd(socket_descriptor)
      # Use TCP keep-alive feature
      socket.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
      # Maximum keep-alive probes before asuming the connection is lost
      socket.setsockopt(Socket::IPPROTO_TCP, Socket::TCP_KEEPCNT, 5)
      # Interval (in seconds) between keep-alive probes
      socket.setsockopt(Socket::IPPROTO_TCP, Socket::TCP_KEEPINTVL, 2)
      # Maximum idle time (in seconds) before start sending keep-alive probes
      socket.setsockopt(Socket::IPPROTO_TCP, Socket::TCP_KEEPIDLE, 2)
      socket.autoclose = true
      return Connection.new(conn, socket)
 end
```

The reason why I introduce a proxy `Connection` class is because of Ruby tendency to garbage-collect `IO` objects (like sockets) when they get out of scope. This means that we now need connection and socket to be in the same scope, which is achieved through this proxy class. My Ruby knowledge is not deep, so there may be a better way to handle the socket object.

This approach works, but I would be happy to learn if there are better/cleaner solutions.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this together - super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

[The link you provided has the answer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-firewall-guidance.html). I think you just want to follow the section at the top, which has settings for 3 different OS'es, pick the one you are running the code on (the client to the Amazon service).

Look in this section: To change TCP/IP timeout settings - this is the OS that your code is running on (i.e. The client for the Amazon Service is your Server probably)

Linux — If your client is running on Linux, run the following command as the root user.

-- details omitted --

Windows — If your client runs on Windows, edit the values for the following registry settings under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters:

-- details omitted --

Mac — If your client is a Mac, create or modify the /etc/sysctl.conf file with the following values:

-- Details omitted --

Comment: I tried it, it does not work for me unfortunately. Somewhere on SO I've seen that you need to do both (i.e. OS settings and keepalive), but as I said I can't do the second.

Comment: it does not work for me either, both psql and Aginity workbench have the same problem, they hang on long running code long after the back end finished processing..... It seems to work for JDBC, ODBC and Npgsql, I have used keepalive settings with success....